# Rails url path: obj_new_path versus new_obj_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I'm creating a messageboard in Rails and have a model called Post and created one called Reply dependent on Post.

Can somebody explain the difference between the automatically created URL paths?

```
replies_new_path
```

and

```
new_post_path
```

I checked the class and controller names and Rails has done the correct pluralization of Reply.
I do not understand the difference in the order. Any clues?

Comment: It's pretty straight forward - A post `has_many` replies (I assume). So since the post is singular but there is many replies, rails convention dictates that it's `replies_new_path` and `new_post_path`

Comment: @Niall You are pretty right!

Comment: Cool! I'll post an answer to help anyone who sees this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straight forward - A post has_many replies (I assume), so since the post is singular but there are many replies, rails convention dictates that it's `replies_new_path` and `new_post_path`.

Comment: +1 (though I think it should be "there are many" instead of "there is many")

Comment: I thought that it would be because I have resources :post but the replies are defined using get in the config/routes.rb file. Is the order important? What is the convention, new first or object first? BTW, thanks for the reply.